# How to add additional constraints for an Efficient Frontier in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, constraints

I have a table with expected returns and volatility by each asset, also I have the covariance matrix of these assets, and for last, some of these assets being part of Returns Seeking and the remaining assets being part of Liabilities Seeking, I want to add weigh constraitns for Return Seeking and Liabilities Seeking.

I'm using an optimization method to solve an efficient frontier but I want to add two constraints in my optimization problem. My optimization problem is:

```
                 Minimise  Volatility 
                    x
                subject to portfolio returns = target
                           Sum of weights = 1
```

And I want to add two additional constraints
Sum of Returns Seeking Weights = 0.65
Sum of Liabilities Seeking Weights = 0.35
My code is written as:

```
def efficient_return(mean_returns, cov_matrix, target):
    num_assets = len(mean_returns)
    args = (mean_returns, cov_matrix)

    def portfolio_return(weights):
        return portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)[1]

    constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: portfolio_return(x) - target},
                   {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1})
    bounds = tuple((0,1) for asset in range(num_assets))
    result = sco.minimize(portfolio_volatility, num_assets*[1./num_assets,], args=args, method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
    return result


def efficient_frontier(mean_returns, cov_matrix, returns_range):
    efficients = []
    for ret in returns_range:
        efficients.append(efficient_return(mean_returns, cov_matrix, ret))
    return efficients
```

My portfolio list is:

```
lista_labels = ['Global Equity', 'TIPS','Long Duration Bonds – Gov’t / Credit', 'Long Duration Bonds – Credit',
               'High Yield Bonds','Emerging Market Bonds','Real Estate (Broad Market)','Global REITs',
               'Commodities','Private Infrastructure','25-year Government Bond','Broad Hedge Funds (Universe)'
                ,'Public Infrastructure','Tactical Asset Allocation','Core Plus Fixed Income']
```

My Return Seeking list is:

```
lista_RS = ['Global Equity','High Yield Bonds','Emerging Market Bonds','Real Estate (Broad Market)',
           'Global REITs','Commodities','Private Infrastructure','Broad Hedge Funds (Universe)',
           'Public Infrastructure','Tactical Asset Allocation']
```

And my Liabilities Seeking is:

```
lista_LS = ['TIPS','Long Duration Bonds – Gov’t / Credit','Long Duration Bonds – Credit','25-year Government Bond',
           'Core Plus Fixed Income']
```

I want to replicate this table http://prntscr.com/twredz. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does a return seeking of 0.65 mean? the composition of the entire portfolio being 65% on the long side? what does liabilities seeking of 0.35 mean? the composition of the entire portfolio being 35% short positions? and do the return seeking and liabilities seeking components together have to sum to 1?

Comment: Hi, dear Develarist.

Yes, the weights of the asset's that are inside of Returns Seeking Lists must sum 0.65. And the other hand, the weights of the assets that are inside of Liabilities Seeking Lists must sum 0.35. And the sum of weights of all assets (both Returns Seeking and Liabilities Seeking) must sum 1. I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
constraints = (
{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: portfolio_return(x) - target},
{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1},
{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x[x>0]) - 0.65},
{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x[x>0]) - 0.35}
)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.